# Symfony2 service not found

Tags: service, symfony

I have a custom service class:

```
namespace Acme\OpsBundle\Lib;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Monolog\Logger;

class ProductManager
{
    private $m_logger;
    private $m_em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, Logger $logger)
    {
        $this->m_logger = $logger;
        $this->m_em = $em;
    }

    ...
}
```

Defined in config.yml as:

```
services:
    opsbundle.prod_manager:
        class: Acme\OpsBundle\Lib\ProductManager
        arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @monolog.logger]
```

And Im accessing it in a controller via:

```
$repoman = $this->get('opsbundle.prod_manager');
```

But I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Acme\OpsBundle\Lib\ProductManager' not found
>   in C:\apache\Symfony\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on
>   line 1555

This worked at one point but I cant figure out what has changed since then to break it. I have tried clearing the cache and restarting apache.

Can anyone suggest why this would happen?

Comment: What is the path of the ProductManager class file?

Comment: Vadim - you are my saviour. The physical path was symfony/src/Acme/OpsBundle/Library/ProductManager.php so I changed it to symfony/src/Acme/OpsBundle/Lib/ProductManager.php and it now works. Thank you!